# Embeddable Attribute change default size of column

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I want to create a mapped class using JPA and Hibernate. For most of its attributes this class uses multilingual properties. For example it want to have the name attribute in both language LanA and Language LanB.

```
@Embeddable
public class MultiLingualTO {
@Basic
@Column(updatable = true, length = 50, nullable = false, name = "aStr")
public String getLanAString() {
    return lanAString;
}

public void setLanAString(String lanAString) {
    this.lanAString= lanAString;
}


@Basic
@Column(updatable = true, length = 50, nullable = false, name = "lStr")
public String getLatinString() {
    return latinStringh;
}

public void setLatinString(String latinStringh) {
    this.latinStringh = latinStringh;
}

private String lanAString;
private String latinStringh;

}
```

But the length of these strings are different. the default value is 50 but there are times I want to set the value for example 250 or 900.

Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you want to change the length based on who is embedding your component, then yes. The consumers of your `@Embeddable` may define an `@AttributeOverride` for the columns. Something like this:

```
    @Embedded
    @AttributeOverrides( {
        @AttributeOverride(name="aStr", column = @Column(length=250) ),
        @AttributeOverride(name="lStr", column = @Column(length=900) )
    } )
    private MultiLingualTO multiLingualTO;
```

See "2.2.2.4. Embedded objects (aka components)" in the Hibernate Annotations documentation http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/#d0e714

`length` is an integer.